# Removing bridging header steps

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, bridging-header

I am removing the "target-Bridging-Header.h" and also removing it from build settings `SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER (Objcetive-C Bridging Header)`

Do I need switch other flags to off (like **Install Objective-C Compatibility Header** or **Precompile Bridging Header** to off)?

Are there any other steps required to remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, removing the bridging header is enough. But the way to figure this out is to create a new, empty Swift project and see what the defaults are. You are basically trying to get back to that default, so just compare to what you see there. I create little throw-away projects all the time to check how they behave compared to a project I'm having a problem with or have a question about.

Comment: In Xcode, values that are bolded represent non-default values, meaning that someone changed them.

Comment: @MarkoSerbia That isn't quite true. While bolded values mean "non-defaults," lots of values that the default Xcode template sets are non-defaults. Create a new project in Xcode, go to Build Settings, and select "Customized" on the main project pane and you'll see the several dozen settings that are bolded and that the project creator did not change.